# page with just one sublayout sitecore

Tags: sitecore

hopefully will explain this right! Ok, Basically I have a form within my sitecore website. The forms a sublayout. Basically, I want a url with just this form and not the rest of my sitecore site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore works such that URLs are associated with content items.

A sublayout is typically an ASP.NET User Control (`.ascx`) and, as you should be aware, you cannot simply render a `.ascx` file without a `.aspx` file (i.e. a Sitecore Layout).

It seems that you have two approaches.

**One:**

1. Create a content item in your site so that you have a URL.
2. Create a simple layout (`.aspx`)
3. Setup the presentation of that content item such that you are rendering your new layout and your sublayout.

**Two:**

If you are literally just trying to render a form, then do you really need to have a content item? Why not just create a `.aspx` file, load in your user control, and put it in your web root? The URL to your form will be the location you placed your `.aspx` file. When a physical file is found Sitecore will bow out and simply let that page render.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to create a layout (or use the default), then bind the sublayout to a placeholder.

Have you read the documentation? This is in the presentation configuration cookbook on the SDN.